# React State not updating upon data retrieval

Tags: reactjs

My React app is not updating (re-rendering) when it gets user information from firebase from the auth state changing. I looked around and people were saying that the auth state listener had to be bound to the object, which I have done. As you can imagine, the output here is `NO USER!` then `Found user: <user name>` , but `FOUND USER` is never rendered.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: props.user
    };

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        this.state = {user: user};
        console.log("Found user: " + user.displayName);
    }.bind(this));

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.user ? "FOUND USER" : "NO USER");
    return (
      <div>{this.state.user ? this.state.user.displayName : "No user!"}</div>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your network call in `componentDidMount` and use `setState`. `this.state =` will not cause a re-render.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: props.user
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        this.setState({user: user});
        console.log("Found user: " + user.displayName);
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.user ? "FOUND USER" : "NO USER");
    return (
      <div>{this.state.user ? this.state.user.displayName : "No user!"}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I called `setState` earlier and got an error that the method did not exist.

Comment: @RyanCocuzzo try the code I just put in my updated answer. No reason you should be getting that error if you have the above, let me know if you do

Comment: I did and it went through. Haven't run into that. Why does it require listening after the component mounts? `setState` also threw when in the constructor. Note that I'll accept answer when it allows.

Comment: `setState` won't exist yet in the constructor since that part of the class hasn't been initialized yet by the React wrapper. The reason to do it in `componentDidMount` is so that you don't block your entire app from rendering by waiting for a network call in the `constructor`. I'm not actually sure that you even can wait for a network call in the constructor, and the **only** way to modify state properly in React is via `setState`. In your current code, the constructor returns the initial state long before your network call ever comes back

Comment: Interesting, certainly noted.

Answer (score 0):

Move your setState call into a separate method out of your event handler.

```
updateValue = (user) => {
    this.setState({ user })
}
```

Then call updateValue method from inside of your onAuthStateChanged event handler.